# Can you have an INT or DECIMAL field only accept negative numbers?

Tags: mysql, sql

Like an unsigned field but only for negative numbers.

I'm just curious.

Comment: No, you can't do that in MySQL.

Comment: @ypercube pretty sure you can.

Comment: @Woot4Moo: I meant you can't do it in a declarative way (using `CHECK` constraints) and that there is no such datatype (non-positive). Triggers is the root of all evils.

Comment: @ypercube ah yes in that case correct there is no "check".  Agree on triggers, but sometimes a necessary evil :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be accomplished with a `before-insert` trigger.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` trigger triggerName 
BEFORE INSERT ON tableA
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

IF(value > 0) THEN
STOP ACTION  
END IF;
```

Comment: Any reason you're comparing with a string?

Answer (score 4):

You could just use an unsigned int and a minus sign on every insert, update and select.

Comment: but doesn't that invert negative data to be positive?

Comment: @Woot4Moo: Exactly. And then every `SELECT` would convert it back to the negative value it was in the first place :)